# Cakephp 3 events: Function name must be a string

Tags: cakephp, events, cakephp-3.0

In my helper I have the following code :

```
$event = new Event('Helper.Regions.beforeSetBlock', $this->_View, [
            'content' => &$block['Block']['body']
        ]);
EventManager::instance()->dispatch($event);
```

And this is my event listener class:

```
public function implementedEvents()
{
        return [
            'Helper.Regions.beforeSetBlock' => 'filterBlockShortcode'
        ];
}

public function filterBlockShortcode($event) {
               
}
```

In bootstrap.php I registered the event like so:

```
EventManager::instance()->on(
    'Helper.Regions.beforeSetBlock',
    new BlocksEventHandler()
)
```

But i get the following error:

> Error: Function name must be a string
>
> File C:\wamp\www\CookieCMS\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Event\EventManager.php
>
> Line: 387

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering the listener the wrong way, what you are doing there is the way to register a callable, ie you are passing the name of the event for which the callable in the second argument should be invoked.

Listener objects implementing `\Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface` must be passed as the first argument, they themselves provide the names of the events that they want to listen to.

```
EventManager::instance()->on(
    new BlocksEventHandler()
);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Events > Registering Listeners](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one more question, how can i call globally register listeners that are implemented in Helper?

Comment: @MultiLoad I don't understand what you're asking, sorry. But it sounds like it could be something for a new question where you can add proper context.